# GitLab CI/CD removes old artifacts from pages public folder

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to deploy multiple versions of a static website to `public` of GitLab pages from GitLab CI/CD.

My strategy is to have the tag or branch name in the path such as

- `pages.foo.com/project/main/site.html` (branch)
- `pages.foo.com/project/latest/site.html` (tag)
- `pages.foo.com/project/v42.1/site.html` (tag)

So I defined myself a variable `DEPLOY_DIR` that is either set to `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` or `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` using CI/CD's `rules` in conjunction with `if`.

The variable itself works fine and the site gets copied to the correct destination.

However, GitLab pages seems to only keep the result of the **latest** built pipeline. Artefacts resulting from previous pipelines are completely **gone**, even though the destination folders on the pages "webserver" are completely different from one another.

So, for example:

1. commit and push to *branch* `main` => successful pipeline build
2. artefacts are copied to `public/main/site.html`
3. website `pages.foo.com/project/main/site.html` works fine
4. *tag* `v42.1` is created => successful pipeline build
5. artefacts are copied to `public/v42.1/site.html`
6. website `pages.foo.com/project/v42.1/site.html` works fine
7. website `pages.foo.com/project/main/site.html` is **gone** (404)

Here's my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
  - build-pdf
  - deploy-html

default:
  tags:
  - small

build-pdf-doctoolchain:
  stage: build-pdf
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/pdf/*.pdf
      - build/html5/*.html
  image: doctoolchain/doctoolchain:v3.2.2
  script:
    - doctoolchain . generatePDF generateHTML

pages:
  stage: deploy-html
  variables:
    DEPLOY_DIR: "default"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
      variables:
        DEPLOY_DIR: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != null
      variables:
        DEPLOY_DIR: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  script:
    - export
    - echo "deploy dir $DEPLOY_DIR"
    - mkdir -p "public/$DEPLOY_DIR"
    - cp -v build/html5/*.html "public/$DEPLOY_DIR"
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_PIPELINE_ID"
    expire_in: never
    paths:
      - public
```

As you can see, I've already tried to use `artifacts.name` and `artifacts.expire_in`, but both don't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @KJ thanks for your comment! But I think retention time is not my problem. At least not yet. My problem is concurrent pipelines. The artefacts resulting from one pipeline overwrite everything that has been there from previous pipelines, even though the destination folders are completely different (main vs. latest/v42.1)

Comment: You can see on a Gitlab forum https://forum.gitlab.com/t/does-publishing-on-gitlab-pages-remove-old-files/39790/3 that it is designed to delete all Pages, and the only solution seems to be storing the Pages elsewhere (like a Git repo), adding them to every deployment. What if you pushed the artifacts to a git repo with each deployment, and also pushed that same repo to pages through the use of artifacts? The obvious solution would be a change by Gitlab- as this does not seem to be how it should be designed- so consider putting a ticket in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using managed GitLab (On GitLab.com), then this feature (`multiple deployments`) is not enabled in the free version (But it is in Premium, Ultimate versions), but if you have self-hosted GitLab then you should enabled this feature by administrator (It's disabled by-default).

**[Reference:](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/#create-multiple-deployments)**

> On self-managed GitLab, by default this feature is not available. To make it available, an administrator can enable the feature flag named pages_multiple_versions_setting. On GitLab.com, this feature is not available. This feature is not ready for production use.

Select the `Deploy` -> `Feature flags` on the left side project's menu:

[image: feature flags]

Set the `pages_multiple_versions_setting` feature flag:

[image: flat setting]

Then you should configure the path prefix within `pages.path_prefix` scope in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. You can find examples and details on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/ci/yaml/index.md#pagespagespath_prefix) In your case you should extend your `pages` section with the following part:

```yaml
pages:
  path_prefix: "$DEPLOY_DIR"
```

Note:

- This feature is not production ready. You can follow the status of the feature in this ticket: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/422145

Answer (score 0):

you can only have one pages site per GitLab project on GitLab.com free tier. Whatever you upload to the public folder in artefacts will override what was previously there hence why you are experiencing this behaviour.

You CAN do this however it is only for certain accounts as referenced here:

> Tier: Premium, Ultimate Offering: SaaS, self-managed Status: Experiment

Read in full [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/#create-multiple-deployments).

Comment: Funnily enough we found the option to have multiple environments yesterday, too. Fortunately, our gitlab is in fact self-hosted. We are currently debating whether or not it is ok to enable the `pages_multiple_versions_setting` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using self-hosted GitLab, You may enable the feature flag - `pages_multiple_versions_setting`

Detailed Help - `https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/`

However, if you are on gitlab.com you won't see this feature.

Alternately if the file names are getting overwritten you may use this **hotfix** within your .yaml to save the files using timestamps.

`export LATESTBUID=$(date +%d-%m-%y-%H-%M-%s) && mkdir -r /tmp/$LATESTBUID && <copy/create your build at this path> /tmp/$LATESTBUID`

`Note :` You may use append your environment names as well for more description